# How to send object and output param to web api parameters to get or set methods?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api class in my web api project which has an object parameter and an output parameter

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Product> GetProducts(out QueryResult queryResult, GlobalInfo globalInfo)
    {
        var repository = new BusinessRepository();
        return repository.GetAllProducts(out queryResult,globalInfo);
    }
}
```

QueryResult and GlobalInfo class is :

```
class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class QueryResult
{
    private QueryStatus _queryStatus;
    public QueryStatus QueryStatus
    {
        get { return _queryStatus; }
        set { _queryStatus = value; }
    }

    private string _errorCode;
    public string ErrorCode
    {
        get { return _errorCode; }
        set { _errorCode = value; }
    }

    private string _errorText;
    public string ErrorText
    {
        get { return _errorText; }
        set { _errorText = value; }
    }
}

public enum QueryStatus
{
    None,
    Error,
    RecordFound,
    RecordNotFound,
    AccessDenied,
    Succeded
}


public class GlobalInfo
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }

}
```

how to call web api method in console app or asp.net mvc by oject parameter and out object parameter?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

QueryResult result;
var globalinfo = new GlobalInfo{UserName = "user1",UserId = 12,IP = "98.14.0.1"};

var data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(globalinfo);

var methodUrl = string.Format("http://localhost/WebApi/api/products/?queryResult={0}&globalInfo={1}",result,data);
var response = client.GetAsync(methodUrl).Result;
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Product>>().Result;
```

Comment: There is no way an HTTP client can access the value assigned to an `out` parameter of an action method.

Comment: @twoflower, you say correctly, tank's for answer to my question.